# Получение данных с связной таблицы по id Yii AR

Tags: ar, yii

Есть две таблицы: `picture(id,name,tag_id) tag(id,name_tag)`
я их связал в классах модели.
делаю в контролере запрос `picture::model()-findAll()`, получаю все картинки с БД.
потом в предстваление передаю и там уже перебираю и вывожу.

Вопрос: как в представление передать не `tag_id` a `name_tag` по `id`, который относится к этой картинке.

Answer (score 1):

В модели Picture

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'tag'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Tag', array('tag_id'=>'id')),
    );
}
```

В контроллере

```
$pictures = Picture::model()->with("tag")->findAll();
```

В представлении

```
echo $picture->tag->name_tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Если [связи](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr) вы сделали правильно, то как то так (ну, текст может меняться от того как у вас связи названы):

```
/**
 * где:
 * $picture - модель таблицы picture
 * $picture->tag - модель таблицы tag
 */
$picture->tag->name_tag
```

Comment: я передаю свои данные в представление.. Тое сть у меня есть следующий код 
$this->render('index',array(
   'dataProvider'=>Picture::model()->findAll()
как мне в представлении дсотучаться до имени таг